# iOS app compiles but crashes on launch when using unsupported 3rd party SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, crash

I have recently dropped the support of iOS 9 in one of my SDKs and set the minimum target version to iOS 10. This has caused some of the users of my SDK who updated to the latest version  of SDK to face an unusual crash in their apps as they are still supporting iOS 9.

My SDK is a dynamically linked library, and the app running on iOS 9 devices crashes even before `main()` is called. I have tried setting the library to be optional in the build phases, but that doesn't stop linking the library at run time. I can't seem to capture the point where the library is linked and somehow make an exception for the unsupported iOS versions.

Is there anyway to avoid this crash on the lower versioned devices right within the SDK? Or this can only be handled from the app integrators end?

Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you are supplying a binary framework and not a source package then the app integrator either needs to set a higher minimum ios level for their app or drop your framework

Comment: Thanks so much for your input. This is what I was afraid of. So I'l just inform the integrator of this and they have to make a decision on their side.